# slds for output form

Tags: visualforce, slds

What I need to achieve is something like the below image got from standard contact detail in LEX: 
[image]

I have searched through the slds document but didn't find much things related to those output fields. What I have tried is write something similar to input field:

```
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label">Message Name</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <span class="uiOutputText">{!message_name}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It looks not too bad... But the margin is not right, and the dividend line is not there. I think the dividend line is kind of achieved by ::after or ::before rather than a `<hr/>` tag. But I can't find where it is by looking at the developer tool. Can someone please help to point me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:
https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/#flavor-input-input-read-only

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
  <span class="slds-form-element__label">Input Label</span>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-has-divider--bottom">
    <span class="slds-form-element__static">Read Only</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

> The read-only state is for form elements that can’t be modified. It is
>   used for small, non-editable form fields that sit next to inputs and
>   allows the size and height to align. It is not meant for large
>   paragraphs of text.
>
> Because the read-only field state has no `<input>`, don’t use a `<label>`
>   to provide better accessibility for screen readers and keyboard
>   navigators. Instead, use a `<span>` with the .form-element__label class.
>   Instead of an `<input>`, use the .form-element__static class inside the
>   .form-element__control wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for this. Not sure why I missed that in the form page... It seems to me it is the slds-has-divider--bottom that does the job. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @LanceShi - My pleasure